# Receive two times the same parameter name with a Java REST API

Tags: java, rest

With this:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public String foo(@RequestParam(value="test", defaultValue="foo") 
String t) {
    return t;
}
```

I can call my function with `curl localhost:8080/foo?test=helloWorld` and it will return `helloWorld`. However, I need to create an API where the same parameter can be giver x times:

```
curl localhost:8080/foo?test=helloWorld&test=helloAgain&test=oneMoreTime
```

So here we go:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public String foo(@RequestParam(value="test", defaultValue="foo") 
String[] t) {
    return t[1];     // return helloAgain
}
```

And now I can get all three values by changing the index. This work great but I have a simple problem: how do I choose my array length? I don't how many time I will receive the same parameters.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "choose"? If the method is called with two `test` parameters, then `t.length` will be 2, if it is called with 5, then `t.length` will be 5 ...

Comment: You have an array as an input parameter, but your foo function is returning single string. You have all test elements in `t[]` array, but what you need to do with this values?

Comment: We can't tell you what your requirements are. Your code is supposed to solve a **problem**. You told us about your code, not the problem you have to solve. So, I would say: return the first param. Or the last. Or join them with "42" in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the the same parameter x times in the @RequestParam, you could use an array (like your second example) but you can't "choose" (define) the size there, but you can get the length. The correct sintaxis is this one:

```
    @RequestMapping("/foo")
public String foo(@RequestParam(value="test") String[] t) {

   Integer size = str.length;
 return t[1];     // return helloAgain

}
```